# {{#each}} makes handlebars template disappear

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a template inside a script tag

> ```
> <div class = "exhibitionDescription">
> <h3>{{title}}</h3>
>   <p>{{infoText}}</p>   </div>
> ```

and the browser renders it fine,

but when I surround it with {{#each arrayName}} {{/each}}

> {{#each arrayName}}
>
> ```
> <div class = "exhibitionDescription">
> <h3>{{title}}</h3>
>   <p>{{infoText}}</p>   </div>
> ```
>
> {{/each}}

browser renders the script tag absolutely blank.

The handlebars library is included before the script tag
(here is a screenshot of the final browser output)

[image]

Here is the same code, but without the {{#each}} {{/each}} around the template

[image]

**UPD**! Turns out {{#each}} tag "cuts" everything it surrounds, including itself, which is not something is that supposed to happen...

**UPD** 2! I think i've got the problem - double curly brackets ({{ }}) just make the code in between disappear! Why tho?

Comment: What type of object do you pass in Handlebars.render method as second parameter? I suspect you are sending arrayName as a single object, #each expects array of objects.

Comment: so i compile the template with Handlebars.compile, sending there a jquery-selected object with id of  "exhibition-template", there i send an object of arrays, one of which is called "arrayName". But the problem is the html i send into the compiler is blank

Answer (score 0):

I solved it - I was using handlebars to insert the templates themselves, that's why my curly braces were interpreted by handlebars as data inputs, and it just removed them when rendering!

Instead of

> `{{text}}`

, I should have used the

> `\{{text}}`

, which fixes the problem and makes it leave the curly braces alone.